# TigerGraph Data Load using HEADER and INPUT_LINE_FILTER

Tags: tigergraph

I am trying to create a TigerGraph loading job to use column names from the header line instead of positional parameters like $1, $2 etc. In order to use files external to TigerGraph server, I believe we need to specify the HEADER and INPUT_LINE_FILTER and use them in the loading job. However, I am unable to find any examples in TigerGraph documentation. My attempt below is now working.

Any help is appreciated.

```
result = conn.gsql('''
USE GRAPH MyGraphCopy 

BEGIN
CREATE LOADING JOB load_persons_byname FOR GRAPH MyGraphCopy {
      DEFINE FILENAME MyDataSource;
      DEFINE HEADER MyHeader = "id","name","email","username","created_at","v_id";
      DEFINE INPUT_LINE_FILTER reject_header = ( "created_at " = "created_at");
      LOAD MyDataSource TO VERTEX Person VALUES($"v_id", $"name", $"email", $"username", $"created_at") USING SEPARATOR=",", HEADER="true", USER_DEFINED_HEADER=MyHeader, REJECT_LINE_RULE=reject_header, EOL="\n", QUOTE="double";
    }
END
''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DEFINE HEADER` and `DEFINE INPUT_LINE_FILTER` lines. If you are reading from a CSV, then simply using `header="true"`; that should be enough to get the references for the column names without doing anything else.

Also, make sure you specify the name and location of the file you are trying to use as `MyDataSource`. Here is an example, where the filename is `file1`:

```
CREATE LOADING JOB load_social FOR GRAPH social {
   DEFINE FILENAME file1="/home/tigergraph/personAndFriendship.csv";

   LOAD file1 TO VERTEX person VALUES ($"name", $"name", $"age", $"gender", $"state") WHERE NOT ($"age" IS EMPTY) USING header="true", separator=",";
   LOAD file1 TO EDGE friendship VALUES ($0, $1, $5) USING header="true", separator=",";
}
```

Also, see [the official TG loading job documentation](https://docs.tigergraph.com/gsql-ref/current/ddl-and-loading/creating-a-loading-job).

Comment: This solution would only work if my file was on the TigerGraph server. I am loading data from external sources using the Python or Java client and the file name cannot be hardcoded. The loading process also cannot copy the file to the TigerGraph server.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to get it to work.

```
USE GRAPH MyGraph

BEGIN
CREATE LOADING JOB load_persons_byname FOR GRAPH MyGraphCopy {
      DEFINE FILENAME MyDataSource;
      DEFINE HEADER MyHeader = "id","name","email","username","created_at","v_id";
      DEFINE INPUT_LINE_FILTER reject_header = ( $4 == "created_at");
      LOAD MyDataSource TO VERTEX Person VALUES($"v_id", $"name", $"email", $"username", $"created_at") USING SEPARATOR=",", HEADER="true", USER_DEFINED_HEADER="MyHeader", REJECT_LINE_RULE=reject_header, EOL="\n", QUOTE="double";
    }
END
```